# Android Listview with clickable buttons

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a `ListView` in which there are 3 buttons. All of them can be clicked. This is a  custom `ListView` with a separate `CustomAdapter` class.

I want to click a button which will take it to `another activity` and the second button will `remove the row` from the list

How can I do it? please help.

Comment: Use custom listview I think it will help you

Comment: I have used custom listview,made my buttons focusable property to false, can print a message in log when the button is clicked,but it is inside the public adapter class, i cannot refer to the activity as it is a separate class and hence also cannot generate intent to send it to other activity.

Comment: Can u please atleat tell me how to remove a row from list when a button in it is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

By using this method you can get Listview item position.and then whatever you need to set.

`public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
   selection.setText(items[position]);
   }`

I hope this will helpful to you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
For this we have to customize the layout instead of listview. it is not possible with listview because listview takes items so individual onclick methods developing is not possible.see the following code. it will help you alot.

Activity:

package com.example.customlistexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchResults extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** create a new layout to display the view */
        final LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);

        String listData[] = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};





            for (int i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {

                TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
                tv1.setText(listData[i]);
                tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,50,Gravity.LEFT));
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 22);


                    ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(this);
                    iv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50, 50,Gravity.LEFT));
                    iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);




                    ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
                    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    iv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,50,Gravity.LEFT));




                    final LinearLayout ll3 = new LinearLayout(this);
                    ll3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    ll3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));
                    ll3.addView(tv1);
                    ll3.addView(iv1);
                    ll3.addView(iv2);
                    ll3.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 25);


                    mainLinearLayout.addView(ll3);

                    final LinearLayout ll5 = new LinearLayout(this);
                    ll5.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, 1));
                    ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
                    mainLinearLayout.addView(ll5);
                    mainLinearLayout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 30);

                    iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            startActivity(new Intent(SearchResults.this,SecondActivity.class));

                        }
                    });
                    iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mainLinearLayout.removeView(ll3);
                            mainLinearLayout.removeView(ll5);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

}

Layout:


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchResults" >

 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_results"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Results"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#800000"
                android:textSize="22px"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

try this definately helps you. Let me know your doubt is clarified or not.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, i have figured it out like this:

To make one of the button of a row take me to another activity-

I have created a private adapter class inside the main activity,when i click on that button, its onClickListener invokes another public function inside the Activity,which inturn fires the intent for another Activity.

But I am still not sure how to remove a row on clicking a button in it.